# AngularJS fixed header background change depending on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a homepage that have a full height div with a video on it. My header is positioned as fixed and is transparent with white letters when on top of this video. When I scroll down I'm calculating the window height and making it have a white background with black letters.

My header looks like this right now.

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header onVideo" role="banner" menuscript>
```

and when I scroll I lose this onVideo class like this:

```
app.directive('menuscript', function ($window, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var w = angular.element($window);

            w.bind('scroll', function(){
                if (w.scrollTop() < w.height() - $('#masthead').height()) {
                    $('#masthead').addClass("onVideo");
                }else{
                    $('#masthead').removeClass("onVideo");
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine. But what should I do if the client changes pages or enters the site on a page that is not home? The other pages don't have this video. On all other pages the header should be white with black letters, or don't have this onVideo class. The scroll also needs to be disabled. After they come back to the homepage this should start working again.

I'm banging my head against the wall already.

**@TL;DR;**
What I need is to remove a class from header and unbind scroll event when the user changes routes. Check if the destination is home. If it is home, add that class back and bind the scroll back. If not, keep header without that class and unbind scroll.

Comment: But document.ready is called only once, when the first page is loaded. If I change pages I'm not really changing pages, angular is just loading another partial into view. It is not that simple.

Comment: Oh!! Then my comments are not valid!!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle demo??

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route. You could use $routeChangeStart like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(evt, next, current) {
  if (next) {
    if (next.templateUrl === 'home.html') {
      $rootScope.showVideo = true;
    } else{
      $rootScope.showVideo = false;
    }
  }
}
```

What you can do with this is determine when your user is changing pages. You can check which page they are moving to and you can set a variable on your $rootScope which you could then use in your header controller to determine if the video and other formatting is shown.

for example:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('CtrlHeader', function CtrlHeader($log, $rootScope, $scope) {

    $scope.showVideo = $routeScope.showVideo;
  });
```

Comment: This looks ok but this is changing the video visibility I guess.

I got close to make it work like this: <header id="masthead" class="site-header {{pageClass}}" role="banner" menuscript> and at my controller I added $rootScope.pageClass = "onVideo"

Comment: This way it shows up correctly when I'm at the home page and after I load another window. But I still need to unbind the scroll and bind it again if the pageClass is onVideo. I can't get this binding and unbinding to work :(

Comment: Why not use an ng-if along with a boolean set from the $rootScope so that you show a different block of header html depending on wether you want to show the video or not. That way when you move to a different page, the menuscript directive should be removed from the DOM and you don't need to worry about unbinding. So: <header ng-if="showVideo == true" id="masthead" class="site-header onVideo" role="banner" menuscript> and next to it <header ng-if="showVideo == false" id="masthead" class="site-header onVideo" role="banner">

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. What I need is: when loading a new page into view, unbind my current scroll script, check if that new page is home. if it is, bind it again. If it is not, remove the onVideo class from header and unbind the scrolling.